# Where is Gemma Arterton in The Wrath of the Titans?

Tags: casting, wrath-of-the-titans

I've just been to see Wrath of the Titans, Gemma Arterton is credited very highly however I did not see her in a single scene?

Is she in the film?

If so where?  If not why is she credited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know her character from *Clash of the Titans* was replaced by Rosamund Pike in '*Wrath*' - are you confusing the two films?

According to Gemma's [IMDb page](http://themovieblog.com/2012/review-wrath-of-the-titans/), she is not in *Wrath of the Titans*

I haven't seen the newest film, so I cannot verify this though.

**UPDATE (with SPOILER)**

According to a review on the [MovieBlog](http://themovieblog.com/2012/review-wrath-of-the-titans/):

*Gemma Arterton’s character Io, is no longer present as we learn she finally has died, a gift in some ways as Zeus granted her mortality. However her death did not come without a sense of happiness, as she bore Perseus’ son, Helios (John Bell), whom he now raises alone.*

Every other site I visited claimed she was not in the film - so now I am doubly confused ;)

Comment: I believe Rosamund Pike's character was Andromeda replacing Alexa Davalos from the first film.  On IMDB you are correct she is not listed, however she is Flixter and (I could be wrong) but I think she was listed on the credits of the film itself

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 2):

Gemma Arterton could not reprise her role as Io because she was filming Hansel and Gretel: Witch Hunter.